# Syntax in Haskell "Functor [::]"

Tags: haskell, functor

I came across the instance `Functor [::]` [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.2.0.0/doc/html/Data-Functor.html) but I don't understand the syntax and didn't find that anywhere in the code. What is the documentation saying?

Comment: Looks like it could be an instance for Data Parallel Haskell lists (http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/GHC/Data_Parallel_Haskell) but given the old version I could very well be mistaken

Comment: Yes, `[::]` is DPH array syntax.

Comment: Guys post the comment as your answer, otherwise I will grab it :)

Comment: Ya, that appears to be the case. Thanks guys!

Comment: @TomSavage as Ankur says, that's the answer, you should post it :-)

Comment: Oh OK then. If you guys insist :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's an instance for [Data Parallel Haskell arrays](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/GHC/Data_Parallel_Haskell).